# Android override recent apps button

Tags: android

Is it possible to override recent apps button on android version 3.0 and above? I am trying to create a lock screen and i've seen that it is possible to override home key onLongClickListener() but find any method to either remove all apps or disable that button.

Please help!

Comment: No, you can't override the recent apps button.

Comment: Is it possible to hide/empty the recent apps list programmatically?